# Bingo game, trouble subtracting, resetting counter tracking squares clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Problem

Currently, if you select a square in a row, but then unselect it and then click the remaining 4 squares in that row, you still receive a "Bingo!" because the counter is just counting the squares clicked.

1. So, I'm wondering how to change it so that unselecting a square will subtract one from the counter.
2. And clicking the "Play Again" button `.again` will reset that counter to 0.

**FIXED JSFIDDLE LINK:** http://jsfiddle.net/tygqfhpq/

### scripts.js

```
$(function() {

    // Set winning combinations to array
    var winners = [
        ['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5'],
        ['b1','b2','b3','b4','b5'],
        ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5'],
        ['d1','d2','d3','d4','d5'],
        ['e1','e2','e3','e4','e5'],
        ['a1','b1','c1','d1','e1'],
        ['a2','b2','c2','d2','e2'],
        ['a3','b3','c3','d3','e3'],
        ['a4','b4','c4','d4','e4'],
        ['a5','b5','c5','d5','e5'],
        ['a1','b2','c3','d4','e5'],
        ['a5','b4','c3','d2','e1']
    ];
    var possibleWinners = winners.length;

    // Initialize selected array with c3 freebie
    var selected = ['c3'];

    // Play again, removes all previously clicked
    $('.again').click(function(){
        $('.square').removeClass('clicked');
        $('.square').css("pointer-events", "auto");
        $('h1').html("WHL Playoffs Bingo");
        selected = ['c3'];
        var counter = 0;
    });

    // Toggle clicked and not clicked
    $('.square').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');

        // Push clicked object ID to 'selected' array
        selected.push($(this).attr('id'));

        // Compare winners array to selected array for matches
        for(var i = 0; i < possibleWinners; i++) {
            var cellExists = 0;

            for(var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if($.inArray(winners[i][j], selected) > -1) {
                    cellExists++;
                }
            }

            // If all 5 winner cells exist in selected array alert success message
            if(cellExists === 5) {
                $('h1').html("Bingo!");
                $('.square').css("pointer-events", "none");
            }
        }
    });

    // Count the number of squares clicked
    $('.square').data('clicked', 0)
        .click(function(){
            var counter = $(this).data('clicked');
            $(this).data('clicked', counter ++);
            console.log(counter);
        })
});
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Election Bingo</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/print.css" media="print">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<h1>WHL Playoffs Bingo</h1>
<p class="teaser">Brandon Wheat Kings to face off against Kelowna Rockets in the finals</p>
<div class="buttons">
    <button class="print" onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
    <button class="again">Play again</button>
</div><!-- /.buttons -->

<div class="bingo">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="square" id="a1"><p>Hat trick</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="b1"><p>Wheat Kings awarded a penalty shot</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="c1"><p>Home team gets on the board first</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="d1"><p>The game goes to OT</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="e1"><p>One-timer</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="square" id="a2"><p>Puck hits the pipes</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="b2"><p>Empty net goal</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="c2"><p>Players drop the gloves</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="d2"><p>Papirny gets a shutout</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="e2"><p>Kelowna comes from three down to steal the game</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="square" id="a3"><p>Fans pack a sold-out Keystone Centre</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="b3"><p>Tyson Baillie saves the day for Kelowna</p></div>
        <!-- <div class="logo"><p>Logo</p></div> -->
        <img src="assets/img/sun.jpeg" alt="" class="logo">
        <div class="square" id="d3"><p>Peter and John Quenneville set each other up</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="e3"><p>“Breakfast goal” worthy numbers against Rockets</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="square" id="a4"><p>Wheat Kings' NHL draft prospects score</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="b4"><p>Wheat Kings kill a power play</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="c4"><p>Players hug it out after scoring a goal</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="d4"><p>Five hole to score</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="e4"><p>Short-handed goal</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="square" id="a5"><p>Scoreless after one</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="b5"><p>One of the Wheat Kings four rookies score</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="c5"><p>Tim McGauley scores</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="d5"><p>Kelowna’s Rourke Chartier adds to his goal total</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="e5"><p>Papirny makes an “impossible” save</p></div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.bingo -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see that your pushing to the selected array, but I don't see anything that removes it if it's toggled off.

Comment: Also - that fiddle leads to a confetti thing.

Comment: Your jsfiddle looks different from the codes posted.

Comment: What's the point of the counter anyways? Couldn't you just use the count from the `selected` array as the active number of squares clicked? (so you can remove or activate a square based on active or otherwise).

Comment: Fixing JSFiddle link now. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/tygqfhpq/

Comment: @Veo Thanks for the heads up. The link has been fixed, could you post a code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your click function:

```
$('.square').click(function(){
    // Toggle the "clicked" class for the item
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');

    // If toggleClass added the class (ie: selected the square)
    // we need to add it to the "selected" array
    if($(this).hasClass("clicked"))
    {
        selected.push($(this).attr('id'));
    }

    // If toggleClass removed the class (ie: deselected the square)
    // we need to remove this item's id from the "selected" array
    else
    {
        // we get the position of $(this) item's 'id' that was previously pushed into the array
        var idx = selected.indexOf($(this).attr('id'));
        // we then remove it from the selected array with splice.
        selected.splice(idx,1);
    }

    // ... remainder of code
}
```

Basically, you were adding the item's id to the clicked array when it was clicked, but not removing it if it was deselected.

Comment: Yup. That works. Could you explain a little more what you are doing here in this code sample.

Comment: Ok, I added some comments. Hopefully that clears it up. Let me know. :)

Comment: Definitely helps. Thanks a bunch!